# Why is this javascript function inside parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, scope

I was looking for a solution to a problem and I found this aswer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6962808/2724978

The function written is:

```
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            doSomething();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
```

My question is, why is the function insite parenthesis an also having () at the end? It got me a bit confused, never seen this before.

Comment: because the function is not being evaluated.

Comment: The 2 parenthesis at the end is to call the loop function. The block is between in parenthesis is a special notation to make everything inside private (not accesible from outside).

Comment: If you type `function loop() { ... };` then that **defines** the function. It is not *executed* yet. Invoking the function is done by `()` (which is argument list) and that actually executes the function. You place a name before `()` and you get `loop()` which tells the JS engine to execute the function.

Comment: @Walfrat: the parens do nothing to make what's inside any more or less private.

Comment: It is called immediately-invoked function expression. The code will executed immediately but has its own private scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781551/javascript-iife)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yes i know i was more telling about the whole block with the parenthesis and the function call.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

The link above will explain all you need to know, but essentially there are two things happening.

- Wrapping within parenthesis tells the parser to treat everything within them as an expression.
- Calling the expression (with `()`) immediately afterwards ensures the scope of that expression is sealed.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet creates an anonymous function, and immediately calls it.

The problem with doing without parens,

```
// This is a syntax error
function () {
  something;
}();
```

is that that is a syntax error; because the statement starts with 'function', the parser expects a function name to follow. Wrapping it all in parens makes it syntatically legal to define an anonymous function there.

```
// This is valid syntax
(function () {
  something;
}());
```